# Multiple columns in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

**Question:** In reference to the attached snap-shot I want to ask how can I create  Type, Quantity, Fees columns in Crystal Report?

**Details:** In the snap-shot there are three types shown which are definite but in my scenario they will be dynamic (means could be 4 , 5 or more)

*Help Required!*[image]

Comment: use cross tabs in dynamic case

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work in 'Detail' Section.

Comment: what problem you are facing when used crosstabs?

Comment: It shows a circle with a inclined line (indicates disable) when i try to use it

Comment: you can't place a cross tab in details section instead use in other sections... either group or report

Comment: but i want to use it in details section :)

Comment: To the extent I know you can't use in `Details` but what difference you see if used in details and other sections?

Comment: i did not get it. the snap-shot is the exact desired layout? the difference would be the number of column "type" occurrences? i mean, you hav BI, CW, MS and more?

Comment: A cross-tab is what you want, but in the Report Footer (or Group Footer depending on your layout). That image is showing aggregated data, which doesn't make sense to place in the Details Section since that section only represents a single record in your report.

Comment: @ Ryan: You are right, I want it in my footer section. But how to achieve that?

Comment: @heringer yes, it could be BI,CW,MS and NT or ML as well for some transactions.

Comment: may you describe your datasource? is it a dataset?